# convert date and time format in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

How to convert datefield of format `mm/dd/yyyy` to format `dd/mm/yyyy` and timefield of format `24hrs to 12hr AM/PM.`

This is i am using in below circumstances

In database from a model i am getting values,so if the values getting from db is '0' the date and time format should be of `(dd/mm/yyyy and 12hr AM/PM).`

If the value from database field is '1',the format is of `(mm/dd/yyyy and 24hr)`

models.py

```
class Report(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=False)
    manual_date = models.DateField('Another date', null=True, blank=True)
    manual_time = models.TimeField('Another time', null=True, blank=True)

class Settings(models.Model):
    date_format = models.CharField('Date format', max_length=100)
time_format = models.CharField('Time format', max_length=100)
```

How to do.

Thanks

Comment: do you want this is the view? or the template ?

Comment: i want it in  views.py

Comment: Can you add some info about the code in your models, and maybe in your view? So we can have something to work with?

Comment: @Paulo Bu updated my views and models

Comment: @karthikr any idea how to convert it in views

Answer (score 2):

I think you are better off handling this converts at the template level using the tag `date`. For example, I see you pass the `date` and `time` variables to the template. Just pass them unconverted and later in the template wherever they appear do this:

```
{% if condition %}
    {{date|date:"DATE_FORMAT"}}
    {{value|time:"TIME_FORMAT"}}
{% endif %}
```

where `"TIME_FORMAT"` is the actual format that you want the date to be showed and condition is the condition that needs to be met.

If you absolutely need to do this within the view method, then you can use the module `django.utils.dateformat` like this:

```
from django.utils.dateformat import DateFormat, TimeFormat
formatted_date = DateFormat(date_variable)
formatted_date.format('Y-m-d') # substitute this format for whatever you need
formatted_time = TimeFormat(time_variable)
formatted_date.format('h') # substitute this format for whatever you need
```

Use that class wherever you want to format your `date_variable` and `time_variable` with the proper format string for them.

Also, about your views' code. You can't just return a string in the middle of a view method like you do:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    if user.date_format == '0':
        date=datetime.datetime.strptime('%m/%d/%Y').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
        return date
```

That will throw an exception if the request method is `POST`. Besides, what date are you formatting there? You need to format your `report.manual_date`. I don't see that anywhere in the code. Apply what I said above to the variable you want to format depending on **your** settings and pass that variable to the `tempalte_context` when you return.
I hope it helps!

Comment: ,I can accept your answer,but i had made some changes in my views and taken the date and time variable in template for display.Is it possible to pass that variable in form,so that the format changes will happen in form field.I updated my views and forms in question.Can you give me some tips

Comment: I think you asked that in another question and someone answered you. Didn't that worked? If not? Refer me to that question because that's a different topic I guess. Can you put the link?

Comment: I am sharing that link two links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16461862/passing-variable-to-a-form-for-display-in-django#16462121

Comment: Paul,with reference from above post i can write this module "django.utils.dateformat" in views right

Comment: Yes you can. `from django.utils.dateformat import DateFormat`.

Comment: let me tell my requirement is,user can enter date in manual_date field so the default format is mm/dd/yyyy but meanwhile a setting page is their where he can customize the date format,so i fixed two choices and for 1st i set as 0 and 2nd i set as 1.So depend on the value saved in db,format should change in form field,in your expalnation the fields are displaying as variable.I think now you can catch it what i am looking.

Comment: I'm a bit confused between the two questions. I just posted an answer to the other question concerning initial data to the forms. This question is about converting date formats. Try my answer there about that topic. Good luck!