# Passing variable to a form for display in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

views.py

```
def when(request):
    user = request.user
    report = Report.objects.get(user=request.user)
    reportform = ReportForm(instance=report)

    settings = Settings.objects.get(user=request.user)
    settingsForm = SettingsForm(instance=settings) 
 #   settings=Settings.objects.get(user=2)
    if settings.date_format == '0':
        date = report.manual_date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    else:
        date = report.manual_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    if settings.time_format == '0':
        time = report.manual_time.strftime('%I:%M%p')
    else:
        time = report.manual_time.strftime('%H:%M')
    if request.method == 'POST':            
        reportform = ReportForm(instance=report,data=request.POST,initial={'manual_date': date,'manual_time': time})
        if reportform.is_valid():
            report = reportform.save(commit=False) 
            report.user = request.user
            report.save()
            return redirect('/member/media/')

    return render_to_response('incident/when.html',{
                  'newreport_menu': True, 
                  'form': reportform,
                   'date':date,
                   'time':time,                  
                   },
                   context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

forms.py

```
class ReportForm(forms.ModelForm):   
    class Meta:
        model = Report
        fields = ['incident_description','manual_date','manual_time', 'location_description',
                  'incident_followup', 'incident_followup_name_1', 'incident_followup_email_1', 
                  'incident_followup_name_2', 'incident_followup_email_2', 'phone_call_log', 
                  'notes_other','notes_firstaid','notes_risk']
    #    manual_date = forms.DateField(input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y', '%d-%m-%Y'],
     #                              widget=forms.DateInput(format="%-d/%-m/%Y"))
        widgets = {'manual_date': forms.DateInput(attrs={'size':'15','id':'datepicker',
            },format='%d/%m/%Y'),'manual_time': forms.TimeInput(attrs={'size':'8','class':'time_field', },format='%H:%M')
         }
```

How to pass the converted date and time format i.e,date and time variable to form.The format what i specified in form is displaying now,but depend on the condition on views,the time and date format should change in form field.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create the form with this line:

```
reportform = ReportForm(instance=report,initial={'manual_date':date, 'manual_time':time})
```

where `date` variable is the date formatted. You will have to move down the instantiation of the form. This would be your code:

```
def when(request):
    user = request.user
    report = Report.objects.get(user=request.user)

    settings = Settings.objects.get(user=request.user)
    settingsForm = SettingsForm(instance=settings) 
 #   settings=Settings.objects.get(user=2)
    if settings.date_format == '0':
        date = report.manual_date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
    else:
        date = report.manual_date.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    if settings.time_format == '0':
        time = report.manual_time.strftime('%I:%M%p')
    else:
        time = report.manual_time.strftime('%H:%M')
    if request.method == 'POST':            
        reportform = ReportForm(instance=report,data=request.POST,initial={'manual_date': date,'manual_time': time})
        if reportform.is_valid():
            report = reportform.save(commit=False) 
            report.user = request.user
            report.save()
            return redirect('/member/media/')

    reportform = ReportForm(instance=report,initial={'manual_date':date, 'manual_time':time})
    return render_to_response('incident/when.html',{
                  'newreport_menu': True, 
                  'form': reportform,
                   'date':date,
                   'time':time,                  
                   },
                   context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

That tries to set manually the initial value of the form already formatted when you instantiate it.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use template tag/filter [date](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date). Define it on the view level and pass to the template:

```
if settings.date_format == '0':
    date_filter = 'd/m/Y'
else:
    date_filter = 'm/d/Y'
if settings.time_format == '0':
    time_filter = 'I:Mp'
else:
    time_filter = 'H:M'
```

In the template:

```
{{ form.manual_date|date:date_filter }}
{{ form.manual_time|date:time_filter }}
```

I'm not sure about the current format but you can always check the reference to get what you want.

PS. Perhaps the view is not the best place to put this code. It's much better to create separate function(s) to handle this.